# In javascript how do I know what type of parameter(s) a function is expecting

Tags: jquery, javascript

**In JavaScript how do I know what type of parameters a function is expecting**? Some people mat say you are making call to function and you must know the types of parameters that function is accepting, but I think this may not be the case always.

Only thing I can think of is using [Function.arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments) and write some code to find the number of parameters and their type.  What is the best practice when it comes to knowing the type of parameter a JavaScript function expect.

Comment: Given javascript's loose typing, usually type doesn't matter as long as the value behaves as it should. The receiving function should make allowance for getting say Strings instead of Numbers, e.g. `a + b` should be say `+a + +b` if either might be a string.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply where good documentation comes in. It's much easier to have an API documentation page that tells you parameters than to programmatically do something like...

```
function derp(uno, dos) {
    var error = [];
    if (!uno) error.push("The first parameter, uno, needs to be a ...");
    if (!dos) error.push("The second parameter, dos, needs to be a ...");
    return error;
}
```

Much easier than ciphering through tons of error arrays.

You can rig something together using the arguments object, but JavaScript is dynamically typed so you can't set a specific type. You can only check and return an error, but you'd have to call this in EVERY method.

Comment: The example has nothing to do with the type of parameters - the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

you may possibly try this:

```
function greet(msg) {
  if(!msg) throw "Parameter message is required !";
  if(typeof msg !== 'string') throw 'Parameter message required of string type !';
  // do the rest below
}
```